# How to let user override SCSS variables when we use @use

Tags: css, sass

I am using `@use` instead of `@import` in my vue project (However, the issue might persist if we don't use vue and use react or maybe plain HTML). I created `_variables.scss` file for the component and let the user override those variables via the user's separate file. Using the below snippet:

```
@use "../app/variables";

$width: 400px;
```

And I include this user's variable override file in my project's entry point.

However, I am unable to override the SCSS variable from user's file. I don't know how can I provide the ability to override variables to users.

Sample CodeSanbox Project: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-sunset-wj8rl?file=/src/styles/user-styles.scss

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

1. You have to include `@use "../styles/user-styles.scss";` in the `styles.scss` file.
2. Change the namespace from `variables` to `user-styles`.

See the [edited CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-curran-d3gdv?file=/src/styles/user-styles.scss).

Comment: Thanks for responding. But I don't want to use `@import` and it will get deprecated in the future. See the conclusion of this link: https://stefaniefluin.medium.com/the-new-sass-module-system-out-with-import-in-with-use-e1bd8ba032d0

Comment: I updated my answer. What about now?

Comment: That's great! This is what I wanted. One last thing I want to ask is that can I make use of `with` to override variables as stated in sass docs for overriding variables. Also, I forget to add !default in variable.

Comment: I have updated the codesandbox.

Comment: I updated my answer. No, you can't use `with` in this case because you get an error (see the image above).

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: You're welcome. :)